# Is there a way to assert that two strings are the same except for one part in python?

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to assert that two strings are the same except for a number. Ex.

```
structure_string = "name|time|mac|type"
string1 = "bob|0|abc|manual"
string2 = "bob|1|abc|manual"
```

I would like to be able to assert that any incoming string matches everything except the time. I need to do this multiple times in tests, so a one liner would be ideal. Something like this

```
assert(incoming_string == "bob|#|abc|manual")
```

Is this possible?

I don't think the sub-string methods would work. I had an idea to check individual pieces of the incoming string against each other, but this is cumbersome.

```
incoming_string_list = incoming_string.split("|")
string1_list = string1.split("|")

assert(incoming_string_list[0] == string1_list[0])
assert(incoming_string_list[2] == string1_list[2])
assert(incoming_string_list[3] == string1_list[3])
```

Comment: you could use .split, if time is always index 1 .pop(1) and then compare lists.

Comment: You can also use a regular expression for this.

Comment: `assert` is a statement in Python, not a function, so you better write it like `assert string1 == string2` (without brackets).

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions are what you want here.

```
import re
assert re.match(r"bob\|\d+\|abc\|manual$", incoming_string)
```

The `\d+` is a placeholder for one or more digits. Note that the pipe characters are escaped because they have a special meaning in regex.

Comment: Okay so if I wanted to do an assert like `assert(incoming_string == string1)`, is there a way to dynamically change string1 into the regex or do I have to manually type out the regex for every test?

Comment: The reason I wouldn't want to type out the regex for every test is that `string1` gets passed in as a parameter, and I don't want to jump through a bunch of hoops to format it into a regex

Comment: But why can't you pass the regex in the first place?

Comment: Regex is just a string, so you can construct it dynamically, but you would need to take care of escaping any characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: Okay @DanielRoseman I didn’t want to get too into detail in the original post but I guess I'm gonna have to. The strings aren't just strings, they're made from a class with the same variables. What I'm actually passing around in pytest is the class instance, and then call a member function that serializes it into the string seen above. I am using this string to check against the incoming string. Im not sure the best way to get a regex from the class instance, or if that is even the best thing to do in this case.

(Should I edit the original question with these updates?)

Comment: `re.match(re.escape('bob|#|abc|manual').replace(r'\#', r'\d+') + '$', incoming_string)`

Comment: I would not recommend updating the question with such specific details, because then it would not be a generally useful question any more.  If you need the serialized strings for something else and you really need to compare them as strings, we don't need to know where they come from.  On the other hand if you are constructing the strings solely for the purpose of comparing them, you can probably completely forget about serializing the objects and compare just the source values, maybe simply by comparing the instances if you define the __eq__() method.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion also works, though I would go with the regular expressions.

```
structure_string = "name|time|mac|type"
string1 = "bob|0|abc|manual".split(sep = "|")
string2 = "bob|1|abc|manual".split(sep = "|")

string1.pop(1)
string2.pop(1)

assert(string1 == string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is likely to use regular expressions, e.g.:

```
import re

structure_string = r"bob\|.*\|abc\|manual$"
test_structure = re.compile(structure_string)
incoming = [
    "bob|0|abc|manual",
    "bob|1|abc|manual",
    "bob|1|abc|manualX",
    "Xbob|1|abc|manual",
    "anne|1|abc|manual"
]

for incoming_string in incoming:
    print(incoming_string, test_structure.match(incoming_string))

assert test_structure.match(incoming[0]), "Not matching: %s ~ %s" % (structure_string, incoming_string)
assert test_structure.match(incoming[-1]), "Not matching: %s ~ %s" % (structure_string, incoming_string)
```

Result:

```
bob|0|abc|manual <re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='bob|0|abc|manual'>
bob|1|abc|manual <re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='bob|1|abc|manual'>
bob|1|abc|manualX None
Xbob|1|abc|manual None
anne|1|abc|manual None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
---> 17 assert test_structure.match(incoming[-1]), "Not matching: %s ~ %s" % (structure_string, incoming_string)

AssertionError: Not matching: bob\|.*\|abc\|manual$ ~ anne|1|abc|manual
```

---

Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#

Good online tool to play around with regular expressions: https://regex101.com/ (explicitly has Python style regexs)